# Is first(where:) Method always O(n) or it can be O(1) with usage of Set or Dictionary?

Tags: swift

I like to know if I use Set instead of Array can my method of `first(where:)` became Complexity:O(1)?

Apple says that the `first(where:)` *Method* is O(n), is it in general so or it depends on how we use it?

for example look at these two ways of coding:

```
var numbers: [Int] = [Int]()
numbers = [3, 7, 4, -2, 9, -6, 10, 1]

if let searchResult = numbers.first(where: { value in value == -2 })
{
    print("The number \(searchResult) Exist!")
}
else
{
    print("The number does not Exist!")
}
```

and this:

```
var numbers: Set<Int> = Set<Int>()
numbers = [3, 7, 4, -2, 9, -6, 10, 1]

if let searchResult = numbers.first(where: { value in value == -2 })
{
    print("The number \(searchResult) Exist!")
}
else
{
    print("The number does not Exist!")
}
```

can we say that in second way Complexity is O(1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still O(n) even when you use a `Set`.  `.first(where:)` is defined on a *sequence*, and it is necessary to check the items in the sequence one at a time to find the *first* one that makes the predicate `true`.

Your example is simply checking if the item exists in the `Set`, but since you are using `.first(where:)` and a predicate `{ value in value ==  -2}` Swift will run that predicate for each element in the sequence in turn until it finds one that returns `true`.  Swift doesn't know that you are really just checking to see if the item is in the set.

If you want `O(1)`, then use `.contains(-2)` on the `Set`.

[image]

Comment: So can I say with **array** and **first(where:)** I would get O(n), But with **Set** or **Dictionary** I would get O(1) Complexity? Is it right?

Comment: If you want O(1) for `Set`, then use `.contains(element)` instead of `.first(where: { $0 == element })`.

Comment: I looked up for **contains(element)** it is same story! Apple says: Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the sequence. I am confused

Comment: No, if you command-click on `.contains` when run on a `Set`, the documentation says it is `O(1)`.

Comment: that is right! I tested! it says: /// - Complexity: O(1) but check for first plz! it says: /// - Complexity: O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the sequence. How we can find THE **N**?

Comment: Right, `first(where:)` is `O(n)` for `Set`.  What do you mean "How can we find THE N"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: So with that said we can say that first(where:) is a O(n) method regardless if we use array or set! But .contains is O(1) for set and O(n) for array. Because I checked it for set says O(1) but for array says O(n)

Comment: That is correct.  `.contains` is O(1) for Sets and O(n) for arrays, but `first(where:)` is O(n) for both.

Comment: And I think .contains is much better than first(where:) because I am trying to find out if that value exist! that was really good one

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to learn more about Big-O notation. O(1) is a strict subset of O(n). Thus every function that is O(1) is also in O(n).

That said, Apple’s documentation is actually misleading as it does not take the complexity of the predicate function into account. The following is clearly O(n^2):

```
numbers.first(where: { value in numbers.contains(value + 42) })
```

Comment: thanks, how you find out about O(2) here? can you plz explain?

Comment: `first`calls the passed function n times in worst case, which in turn calls `
contains` and makes O(n) comparisons, leading to O(n^2) comparisons overall.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Set` and `Dictionary` conform to the `Sequence` protocol, which is the one that exposes the `first(where:)` function. And this function has the following requirement, taken from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907979-first#discussion):

> Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the sequence.

Now, this is the upper limit of the function complexity, it might well be that some sequences optimize the search based on their data type and the storage details.

Bottom line: you need to reach the documentation for a particular type if you want to know more about the performance of some feature, however if you're only circulating some protocol references, then you should assume the "worst" - aka what's in the protocol documentation.

Comment: because Set is hash-able so the app do not need start asking every index of Set to give us a result, because if we are talking about array it would put array in a loop for finding the mach case which it is not the same with Set or Dictionary, that is why I wanted be sure when I am using Set with those method what happens anther hood?

Comment: @Omid unless you have access to the source code, you can't be sure about what happens under the hood. And even if you'd have access, implementation details can change at any time without any warning. This is why it's best to rely on documented behaviour, which changes less often.

Answer (score 1):

This is the implementation of the first(where:) function in the sequence:

```
/// - Complexity: O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the sequence.
@inlinable
public func first(
    where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool
) rethrows -> Element? {
    for element in self {
        if try predicate(element) {
            return element
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

<sub>From the [Swift Source Code on the Github](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift)</sub>

As you can see, It's a simple `for` loop and the complexity is **O(*n*)** (assuming the `predicate` complexity is `1` ‍♂️).

The `predicate` executes **n** times. So the worst case is  **O(*n*)**

The `Set` has not an overload for this function (since it is nonsense and there will be nothing more than the **first** one in a `Set`). If you know about the sequence and you are just looking for a value (not a predicate), just use `contains` or `firstIndex(of:)`. These two have overloads with the complexity of **O(*1*)**

<sub>From the [Swift Source Code on the Github](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift)</sub>

Comment: WoW! that is so cool! how and where you code find that information! that is an old fashioned (for-if) is it this source Code really happing in our Xcode when we are using func first() ? really?

Comment: Check the links. Both are directly from the official Apple's account.

Comment: thanks a lot! that will help a lot to understanding!